# How can I tell the creation date and creator of a file inserted into a MS Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, csv

If I have a Word document and a CSV file was inserted inside the Word document, how can I tell the creation date of the CSV file and the person who created it when I open the CSV file up from within the Word document?
(In other words, simple version control on the CSV file.)